# How to enable reply on comments of profile on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, setting, reply

I know you can enable "reply" feature on Facebook pages
but I want this also be done on my personal profile? 
I've seen a few people on my FB who have this feature enabled on their profile and their friends profiles too.

Does anyone have a guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Google Chrome
2. Open touch.facebook.com and login through your id
3. Now Right click anywhere and click on inspect element
4. Now Click the Setting [gear]
5. Now " Click Overrides " 
   Check/Enable “Override Geolocation”.
   Type/Copy those number in the boxes : Lat = -41.289996 Lon = 174.781555
   Close setting window and KEEP the inspect element window open . See image below :
6. Now Click " Check in "
7. Dont click post , just open a new tab and open facebook.com
8. Done now make a post